# Proceso fantasma en Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, digitalocean

Hace dias que tengo un problema de seguridad en mi servidor con Ubuntu. Cuando reviso los procesos, uno que aparece entre los que mayor consumo tienen es:

> NZInzgIlSJgkD

Alguno tiene idea de que puede ser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ni idea que pueda ser, pero si fuera tu, lo buscaría de esta manera:

Supongo que lo estas viendo en *top*, de ahí me iría a ver la linea de comando:

```
ps -ef | grep NZInzgIlSJgkD
```

Ahí mismo puedes ver cual es el proceso padre (¿quien lo arranco?). Ver las propiedades del archivo con herramientas como `file /pathAlArchivo/NZInzgIlSJgkD`, incluso el usuario/grupo podrían dar pistas.

Siendo que es un nombre generado posiblemente al azar, es probable que no lo encuentres (se ejecuta y se elimina), pero el dato del proceso que lo inicia será tu pista a seguir.

Comment: Realmente estuvo muy complicado encontrarle. En ultimas migre de servidor y bueno pues a cuidarse. Gracias!!